# Double Integral $\iint_D\ (x+2y)\ dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\iint_D (x+2y)\ dxdy $$
If the area is range by $x=2,\ x=3,\ y=x,\ y=2x$,
how to include the lines?  How limits for integral will looks like?

You mean something like this? ( I made mess)

$$\iint_D (x+2y)\ dxdy $$
If the area is range by $x=2,\ x=3,\ y=x,\ y=2x$,
how to include the lines?  How limits for integral will looks like?

So
$$ \int_{y=x}^{2x}\ (x+2y)\ dx =   \int_{y=x}^{2x} x dx + \int_{y=x}^{2x}\  2y dx = \frac{1}2 [x^{2}] + 2y \int_{y=x}^{2x}\  1 dx = \frac{1}{2}(2x)^{2}-y^{2} + 2y(2x-y)  $$

and
$$  \int_{x=2}^3 [ \frac{1}{2}(2x)^{2}-y^{2} + 2y(2x-y) ]dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{x=2}^3 (2x)^{2}  dy - \int_{x=2}^3 y^{2} dy + \int_{x=2}^3 4xy dy - \int_{x=2}^3 2y^{2}  dy = \frac{1}{2} (2x)^{2} \int_{x=2}^3  1 dy - [\ \frac{1}{3}y^{3}] + 4x[\frac{1}{2}y^{2}] - 2[\frac{1}{3}y^{3}]= \frac{1}{2} (2x)^{2}... $$ and I do not know.

Comment: You need to write $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon a\leq x\leq b\land f_1(x)\leq y\leq f_2(x)\}$ or $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon c\leq y\leq d\land g_1(y)\leq x\leq g_2(y)\}$, with $ab,c,d\in \mathbb R$ and for some well-behaved functions $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$. Then the integral becomes, for instance in the first case, $\displaystyle \int \limits_a^b\int \limits_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)}(x+2y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: No. You misinterpret my answer. You should evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{y=x}^{2x}(x+2y)\ dy$ first. See the comments below my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :**
$$
\iint_D\ (x+2y)\ dx\,dy=\int_{x=2}^3\int_{y=x}^{2x}\ (x+2y)\ dx\,dy.
$$

Comment: See [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3D2%2C+x%3D3%2C+y%3Dx%2C+y%3D2x) to visualize the region.

Comment: You mispelled 'answer'.

Comment: It should be $\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @GitGud My Prof says it doesn't matter as long as we include the variable in the limit of integrals so we know what we should evaluate first. For example
$$
\int_{x=2}^3\int_{y=x}^{2x}\ (x+2y)\ dx\,dy=\int_{2}^3\int_{x}^{2x}\ (x+2y)\ dy\,dx
$$

Comment: I see. I didn't know about that notation.

Comment: @GitGud Similar notation is also used in textbook **Schaum’s Outline Series: Probability and Statistics Third Edition** by Murray R. Spiegel and John J. Schiller.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't see that, i calculate it and now is good. answer is $25  \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @GitGud, if the limits of one axis depend on the other, the itereated integrals should of that order.  I agree with you, it could be made wrong if he evaluates it in the wrong order.  I see this confusion in many of the answers from other part of the world.